# Default return value of required method defined in protocol Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, protocols

In my protocol I've created one method with BOOL return value, and I would like to return YES by default. How can I set this?

This is my Implementation:

```
//MyFilter.h

@protocol MyFilter <NSObject>

- (BOOL)filterSomething:(NSString *)something;

@end
```

My idea is to allow some other class (lets say ClassA) to conform to this protocol, and when this method is called to return YES by default, and if ClassA filters this in some other way, to modify return value. I know how to modify it, but I am not sure how to set YES as default.

Comment: Do you mean to say that YES is to be returned if the class does not implement the method, and if it does then return the value from that method?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I can check if class confirms to a protocol, but I am not sure if there is a way to check if method filterSomething exists or not. The thing is Xcode throws only a warning that it is not implemented, so I it is not forcing you to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to check whether a class implements a method:

```
if ([anObject respondsToSelector:@(filterSomething:)])
{
    return [anObject filterSomething:someString];
}

return YES;
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like @ZeMoon suggested, you can use `respondsToSelector:` method to check is this method implemented for specific object. Another possibility is providing default implementation for `NSObject`:

```
@protocol MyFilter <NSObject>

- (BOOL)filterSomething:(NSString *)something;

@end

@interface NSObject (MyFilter) <MyFilter>
@end

@implementation NSObject (MyFilter)

- (BOOL)filterSomething:(NSString *)something {
    return YES;
}

@end

@implementation ClassA

- (BOOL)filterSomething:(NSString *)something {
    // your implementation
}

@end
```

In this case, you can safely call `filterSomething:` for any objects without additional checks:

```
return [anObject filterSomething:someString];
```